# Trouble with edge spacing and relaxing with loop tools

Tags: tools

These are the bevel edges that I want evenly spaced over the curve.

[image: This is what I have so far from my Blender book]

Here is what the book says to do and my goal

[image]

When I try do do the spacing after selecting only the parallel edges, nothing happens. If I include the edges inbetween, this happens
[image]

What might I be doing wrong? I'd appreciate any tips

Comment: Perhaps you're trying to do both ends at the same time? The Loop-tools version works on vertices _along_ a loop.  (One loop at a time) There's the excellent [Edge Flow](https://github.com/BenjaminSauder/EdgeFlow) add-on by Benjamin Sauder which works on parallel edges.

Comment: Thank you for that great recommendation!